# what is different between init() and init(_:bool)

Tags: swift, priority-queue

```
var LocalFile = "xxx.json"
var Delta = false
var priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT

init(){
    priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH
}

init(_:Bool){
    Delta = true
    priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW
}

func getList(postData: Dictionary<String, String>){

    let localdata = readfile(LocalFile)
    if (localdata != "" && Delta == false){}
    else{
    }
}
```

I am just a beginner for learning Swift. When I look through this class, I wonder why this class contains 2 `init()`? How does it work with "priority"?

Comment: That 2nd `init` makes little sense. The parameter is being ignored (and in fact it can't be accessed at all in the implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
init(){
    priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH
}
```

1. It is a `default` constructor. It means your instance variable will be initialized by default with their respective values.
2. Here the priority is HIGH (DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH)

   ```
   init(_:Bool){
      Delta = true
      priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW
   }
   ```

1 . It is `parameterised`, constructor. It means you are initializing Delta while you are creating object of this class.

2 . Here the priority is LOW (DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW)

Answer (score 0):

First, it should be localFile and delta. (notice case).

Second, this is a terribly written API. I'm guessing the creator was wanting two different initializers, one with a high priority and one with a low priority that initializes delta.